# OS X Bash list files excluding items from input file

Tags: macos, bash, inputstream

I need to list the contents of a directory, but exclude a list of known files which are in a plain text file. I'm assuming using grep or input redirection or possibly a while loop but am stuck.

The following works but is long winded:

```
 ls ~/Library/Fonts | grep -v 'Onyx\|Playbill\|Georgia\|Garamond\|Tahoma\|Verdana\|Microsoft'
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ls | grep -v -F -f exclude.file
```

[grep man page](http://bama.ua.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?grep)